# Django: Many To Many Field 'get_or_create' error

Tags: python, django

I have a many-to-many field `group_user` between two models `user` and `group`. And this time, I want to get or create `group_user` but this error below occurs:

The error:

> Cannot resolve keyword 'group' into field. Choices are: Group, Group_id, User, User_id, id

correct `group` and `user` can be found. Group and User are model.

views.py

```
# get or create group user
team_user, created = GroupUser.objects.get_or_create(
    user=user,
    group=group,
    defaults={
        'token': access_token
    }
)
team_user.save
```

models.py

```
class GroupUser(models.Model):
    User = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    token = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.token
```

Comment: I added something to the error message: "Cannot resolve keyword '**g**roup' into field. Choices are: **G**roup, Group_id, User, User_id, id"

Comment: Your model has fields `User` and `Group`. That's wrong.

Comment: You need to name your fields in lower case: user and group, not User and Group.

Comment: Thanks guys! I've got it done!